# JPQL LEFT JOIN is not working

Tags: jpql

I want to get the list of all `Branch` even if they have no accounts with `user` role

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT NEW com.package.BranchInstructors(b,a) FROM Branch b LEFT JOIN b.accounts a WHERE b.dFlg = 0 AND a.userRole = :role ORDER BY b.name ASC");
query.setParameter("role", "user");
return query.getResultList();
```

Unfortunately it's returning only Branches with `user` role, it's like doing INNER JOIN instead.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the `a.userRole is null` condition to your query to avoid filtering the null userRole that you got from the left join

```
 SELECT NEW com.package.BranchInstructors(b,a) 
     FROM Branch b
     LEFT JOIN b.accounts a
     WHERE b.dFlg = 0 
     AND (a.userRole = :role OR a.userRole IS NULL)
     ORDER BY b.name ASC"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `WHERE` vs `LEFT JOIN` clause.

If you use `LEFT JOIN` table `Accounts` and use this table in the `WHERE` with `AND` condition, it behaves like a `JOIN`.

So, you can use `WITH` in the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT NEW com.package.BranchInstructors(b,a) FROM Branch b 
LEFT JOIN b.accounts a WITH a.userRole = :role
WHERE b.dFlg = 0 ORDER BY b.name ASC");
```

Comment: it has error when using `WITH` `Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT NEW com.package.BranchInstructors(b,a) FROM Branch b LEFT JOIN b.accounts a WITH a.userRole = :role WHERE b.dFlg = 0 ORDER BY b.name ASC], line 1, column 93: unexpected token [WITH]`

Comment: What JPA implentation are you using and what version? Try using `ON` instead of `WITH`.

Comment: I'm not sure what version, I'm using JSF 2.1 with Glassfish 3.1.2 but this is the detailed error `Exception [EclipseLink-8025] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT NEW com.package.BranchInstructors(b,a) FROM Branch b LEFT JOIN b.accounts a ON a.userRole = :role WHERE b.dFlg = 0 ORDER BY b.name ASC], line 1, column 93: unexpected token [ON].
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(80@[()* loopback of 477:9: (node= join )*])` i just took over this project

Comment: You are using EclipseLink implementation for JPA. Did you try to use `ON` instead of `WITH`?